# how to export phpmyadmin table into csv?

Tags: sql, excel, csv, phpmyadmin

I want to export a table of a database on phpMyAdmin into csv file. 
I tried `SELECT * FROM Table_Name into outfile'D:/wamp/www/projectName/fileName.csv';` but it's very ugly. How to make it more presentable?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Ugly? Is it CSV or not?

Comment: I want all the attributes of the table to be in separate boxes in my CSV file.

Comment: I did it but all the attributes are in the same box..

Comment: Did you try using the import data from txt source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want it in Excel, in the end? In phpMyAdmin, view the table. In the tabs at the top, choose "Export". Choose whichever Excel format you want from the list at the left-hand side. Choose the options you want, hit "Go".

(If you just want CSV, this screen also gives you a friendly way of adjusting the CSV options, e.g. using a comma rather than a semicolon as the separator, which will probably go down better with Excel and other CSV importers.)

[image: PHPMyAdmin Export Interface]

Comment: Do you know how to do the same in php?

Answer (score 0):

From Excel go to Data - (import) From Text, choose Delimited and select ";"